# Model Validation Not Working

Tags: php, validation, model, yii

I have following action to handle register

```
 $model=new User('checkout');
        if(!empty($_POST['User'])){

            $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
            //echo '<pre>';echo $model->username;die;
            $model->validate();
           echo  $model->getErrors(); die;
        }
        $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model));
```

and model rules are

```
array('username', 'required', 'on' => 'checkout','message' => Yii::t('validation', 'Email can not be blank.')),
            array('username', 'unique', 'on' => 'checkout', 'message' => Yii::t('validation', 'Email has already been taken.')),

            array('username', 'unique'),
            array('passwordConfirm', 'required', 'on' => 'checkout','message' => Yii::t('validation', 'Confirm password can not be blank')),
            array('username', 'email', 'message' => Yii::t('validation', 'Invalid username/email format ')),
            //comapre passwords
```

Form post data is

```
Array
(
    [fname] => hemc
    [lname] => k
    [username] => demo
    [dob] => 
    [password] => 
    [passwordConfirm] => 
    [agree] => 0
)
```

Problem -:There is no error while validating model.

Comment: have you tried using a simple message for username, `'message' => 'Invalid username/email format '` instead of `'message' => Yii::t('validation', 'Invalid username/email format ')`..

Comment: Yeah tried, no success.

Comment: any of your rule is working?? try with a basic rule of required, if not working then problem is with your model data..

Comment: Have you tried using `$model->setScenario('checkout');` right before you `validate()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getErrors`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#getErrors-detail) will return an array, you should try this :

```
var_dump($model->getErrors());
```

or

```
print_r($model->getErrors());
```

PS : you should display errors in your `CActiveForm` with [`errorSummary`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#errorSummary-detail)